# How to add an overlay text to a blurred react component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am developing an application in React and Material-ui that uses a card component to display some information. However, I am not the best at CSS and I am having trouble creating an overlay for the Card component while it is blurred out. I use the css property `filter: blur(2px)` in order to accomplish the blur, but whenever I add any CSS for the overlay it either puts the text under the card over above. My goal would be to have it centered in the middle of the card.

**Code:**

```
import { Grid, Typography, CardContent, Card } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';



const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

    root:{
        width: 400,
        filter: "blur(3px)",
    },

    textOverlay: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }

}));

const LandingPage = () => {


const classes = useStyles();

    return (
         <React.Fragment>
           

            <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justify="center">
                

                <Grid item>
                    <Card className={classes.root}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography variant="h4" align="center" >Monday</Typography>

                            <Typography>Song</Typography>
                            <Typography>Africa</Typography>

                            <Typography>Artist</Typography>
                            <Typography>Toto</Typography>

                            <Typography>Preview</Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                   <div className={classes.textOverlay}> Coming Soon </div>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>


     

        </React.Fragment>

    );
}



export default LandingPage;
```

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of what you're getting and what you expect

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick. Just set the Grid item to position fixed. You may need to add the z-index. But in your example it wasn't needed.

I would also suggest to add the '**notSelectable**' to your blurred content so that the user cant select it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-volhard-72wuh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Typography, CardContent, Card } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 400,
    filter: "blur(3px)",
  },

  textOverlay: {
    position: "fixed",
  }

  notSelectable: {
    userSelect: "none"
  }
}));

const LandingPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justify="center">
        <Grid item>
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent className={classes.notSelectable}>
              <Typography variant="h4" align="center">
                Monday
              </Typography>

              <Typography>Song</Typography>
              <Typography>Africa</Typography>

              <Typography>Artist</Typography>
              <Typography>Toto</Typography>

              <Typography>Preview</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item className={classes.textOverlay}>
          <div> Coming Soon </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```